# Is it possible to inspect iPhone/iPad app in desktop?

Tags: iphone, macos, ipad

*I know that for Android it's possible to use Chrome://inspect to view the phone screen on your desktop. Clicking there is equal to tapping on the phone.*
It's fine for browsers and after 4.4 - for apps that have some special lines of code inserted.

Whether it's possible for iPhone / iPad?
i.e. I have a REAL device with latest OS installed, which screen I'd like to be shown on MAC + clicking on the items on the screen will be equal to tappping on the phone.

Comment: you may do playing with _AirPlay_, but it is not an interactive interface, so literally you won't be able to control the device from the desktop, it is only a read-only projection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

XCode iOS Simulator - I am somewhat surprised you missed this part of the IDE.

Comment: I haven't missed it but I'd like not simulator but my real device